# Как пронавигироваться назад используя navigation component?

Tags: android

Есть home fragment на котором есть кнопка выход. При нажатии на кнопку нужно перейти на экран авторизации (логин). Если создать action на это действие, то навигация выполняется, но появляется возможность вернуться назад на home при нажатии кнопки назад. Как выполнить навигацию на login, убрав из стека все экраны которые лежат под login?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack, https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В action в Вашем случае нужно указать, что фрагмент назначения становится самым верхним в истории:

```
  <action android:id="@+id/action_name"
          app:destination="@id/destination"
          app:popUpTo="@id/destination"
          app:popUpToInclusive="true"
          app:launchSingleTop="true">
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]